# Cast WPF Window to WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Window and UserControl are similar in many aspect,

But Window can not be casted to UserControl simply by put "(Usercontrol) " before a window,

```
Window w = new Window();
Usercontrol u = (UserControl)w;  //not allowed
```

Is there other possible way can cast a Window to Usercontrol?  (without modify the window's code)

Or it's impossible?

Comment: No; those are two unrelated classes.  You should not need to do that; what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: oh because I have a Completed Window class A, and  I have another Window class B, B has a Contentcontrol dynamic binding a usercontrol, and if window A can cast to UserControl, i can directly bind the contentcontrol in B to A

Comment: why do want to cast contentcontrol in B into A (which is a window)? what do want to do by doing this casting?

Comment: just because if it can work, I do the thing above will be really easy.  now i know it can't work, I think if i want to turn A into Usercontrol, i'll do it  by modifying the code, like modify the xaml from <window> to <usercontrol> and so is the class code--------------I explain it more explicitly,  Window B has a ContentControl element call it C,  C's Content can binding to some usercontrol that i can assign, and if I turn A into usercontrol, then I can binding C's content to A, then the content of A can be show in C, and because C is in B, I can success put A into B

Comment: and why i use contentcontrol is because its Content  can dynamically binding to different usercontrol, I can change C's content easily by just change its binding content to UserControl J,K,L.... by some code

Comment: @yuyangJian I don't think that is possible a usercontrol can't be child of two different parents at same time. If you want to show same usercontrol in two views you can make two different objects  of that usercontrol and display that in your different  windows and give them same datacontext. that way only you will have kind of identical views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window does not inherit from UserControl, thus you will not be able to cast it as such.